# Problem with new unregistered users

Tags: discussion, new-users, unregistered-users

There is a lot of problem with new users who have unregistered accounts. They don't understand what stack exchange is for and ask whatever question they feel like. That is not big problem but the real problem is when the have done with finding the answer they close the site forever. They don't bother to upvote or accept a correct answer which deprives regular users of some reputation. Also the ask new questions in comment boxes. What to do?
Please refer to this link-https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1430729/solving-two-rectangles/1430750#1430750

Reputation does not matter much.I use Maths SE to get help and help others.But it is expected that other users will acknowledge fellow users help...

Comment: Why do I have so many downvotes in Meta?? :-0

Comment: Maybe because most users here don't feel it's an issue at all. If you get to 30k like Martin here, you won't worry about not getting the 25 points you deserve when the asker neglects to upvote and accept any answer.

Comment: If I don't like the way something is going as regards answers or comments of mine, I delete them, so i won't need to think about that post any more. Also, if the OP has been bothering me with additional questions, this deprives them of a quick way to bug me.

Comment: @RobertSoupe-But I don't have 30k reputation and there 25 points ,matter to me because these small points will take be to the big 30k.Moreover that is the only way to earn reputation and I have to bother about it to increase  my reputation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as not receiving any reputation from the asker is concerned, as I mentioned in [a previous answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/19390/8348), your options are pretty much the following:

1. Only answer questions where there is a greater likelihood that the asker will respond to your answer in some way. This would seem to require a little reconnaissance *before* posting your answer.
2. Learn to stop worrying and love the ignored answer.

You should also keep the following in mind.

- The [ability to upvote](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) is granted after earning 15 reputation, so it makes no sense to be miffed that a <15-rep user is not upvoting your answers.
- Regardless of how much reputation an unregistered account has, the *only* votes they can cast are accept votes (*i.e.*, they won't be casting upvotes until they register).

---

If you feel that the additional queries in comments is starting to feel like harassment, feel free to stop responding, and to flag the comments for moderator attention. We can then delete them, so you need not worry about them any more. Persistent harassment should also be made aware to us, as we can have "strong words" with the individual.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!But I think that this is a great problem with unregistered users.

Comment: I use Maths SE to get help and help others.But it is expected that other users will acknowledge fellow users help...

Comment: @tatan Stack accepts unregistered users and multiple accounts only to have as many as possible users. This is a long standing policy, and as you can see, many (possible high rated) users agree with this, so nothing can be done.

Comment: @user26857 Thanks for your opinion....

Comment: @tatan I've forgot to say, but maybe it's clear from my previous comment, that I strongly disagree with Stacks policy on this matter.